# How can I NOT to display custom error messages in silent install?

Tags: c#, installation, wix, wixsharp

I'm using `WixSharp` for building an installer.

How can I **NOT** show the user custom error messages during `silent install` only?
I mean - running via `GUI` will show the errors, only via `silent install` not.

For example adding this custom message of disabling repair:

```
 installer.Load += e =>
                {
                    if (e.IsRepairing)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Repair is not supported");
                        e.Result = ActionResult.UserExit;
                    }                       
                };
```

I'm getting the error above while running `repair` either via GUI or via silent mode.
I want to get this via GUI mode only.

Comment: MSI output or .exe?

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary - MSI

Comment: Does it need UAC?

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary- I'm not sure what do you mean by UAC?

Comment: Sorry, elevated privileges? run as admin during the installation?

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary - yes, it needs.

Comment: Try to check `e.UILevel`. This should be 2 for silent installation. See https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/d809ad85510a84849ee0ab0a249d375077c64ef5/Source/src/WixSharp/ManagedProject/SetupEventArgs.cs#L89 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installer-uilevel?redirectedfrom=MSDN for details